# Java List of Points

Tags: java, android, arrays, list, loops

So I'm having a problem with this line of code.

```
private List<PointF> userPath = new ArrayList<PointF>();
pointF movingPoint = new pointF();
pointF initialPoint = new pointF();
initialPoint = (1,1);

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    movingPoint.x = initialPoint.x + i;
    movingPoint.y = initialPoint.y;

    userPath.add(movingPoint);
}
```

So what I want is for the userPath List to have each coordinate,
    [(1,1), (2,1), (3,1)...]

Instead I keep getting
    [(1,1)] first iteration
    [(2,1), (2,1)] second iteration
    [(3,1), (3,1), (3,1)] third iteration

Is there a way I can work around this, since I realize that each element of the List is storing the point object movingPoint and when moving point changes so does every element which contains it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to re-create `movingPoint` at each iteration of the loop.

```
private List<PointF> userPath = new ArrayList<PointF>();
pointF movingPoint = null; // change here
pointF initialPoint = new pointF();
initialPoint = (1,1);

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    movingPoint = new pointF(); // change here

    movingPoint.x = initialPoint.x + i;
    movingPoint.y = initialPoint.y;

    userPath.add(movingPoint);
}
```

If you don't re-create it, since you,re keeping the reference, you're basically adding the same object several times to the list. So any modification to the object `movingPoint` with affect all the objects of the list, since they all have the same reference to the same object.

Comment: +1 Good explanation.  You can also _add_ that an equivalent way to recreate the point is to replace the entire body of the `for` loop with the single statement `userPath.add(new pointF(initialPoint.x+i, initialPoint.y));`

Comment: @RayToal Yes, but if the OP is having trouble here, your solution would scare them off :D

Comment: Fair enough, @AntonH, baby steps it is :)